# Is a password manager better than an encrypted file for storing passwords?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management

For any passwords other than websites I log into regularly (such as Gmail, Facebook, etc.), I use [`apg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/apg) to generate a random 20 character password.  I then add that password and a username or email address to a text file I keep stored in an encrypted VeraCrypt volume (password for that exists solely in my head).

In light of the [Collection #1 breach](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-773-million-record-collection-1-data-reach/), I'm planning to go through and change some of my passwords, and I'm wondering about the benefits of using a password manager such as Encryptr or Gnome Keyring.  I usually use Mint with Cinnamon.

Is storing passwords in an encrypted file considered adequate for most peoples' needs?  Even if it is, are there other benefits to using a password manager?

Comment: Please ping me if this is not a helpful migration. Thanks! (SU ♦)

Comment: @studiohack Not a problem.  Thanks for migrating it.

Comment: A password manager is special-purpose encrypted file with some additional features and better hardening against potential attacks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Having an encrypted text file with passwords in it is certainly better then having common/reused passwords or an unencrypted file.

A good password manager is, however, incrementally better, in the following ways (off the top of my head)

- Better memory management - it can prevent passwords being left in computer memory which can be snaffled by other processes/users.
- It only exposes the needed password, not all of them.
- (Sometimes) Browser integration makes life easier
- Many eyes - a program designed specifically for password management, and audited, likely has stronger processes in place to ensure good hygene.
- Cross-platform compatibility, arguably easier to merge records and manage in a cloud environment/from multiple locations.

You might want to look at Keepass and other variants, and the kdbx format.  (And how well its supported).  I use that under Linux (I assume you use linux as you mention APG)

Comment: Yes, I use Mint.  I didn't realize Keepass worked on linux.

Comment: apt install keepass2

Comment: Also, you may find kpcli helpful.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Does using keepass make cross-platform a problem?  For example, if I want to login from android, is there a way to sync passwords across devices?

Comment: I've not used it on Android yet, but it should work OK if you have a shared system like Dropbox, or even use Webdav or any of a number of mechanisms (included in keepass2Android for example)

Comment: With a password manager you can even copy passwords without showing them on the screen, so people around you won't even see that one password.

Comment: Not to mention that a password manager can autogenerate very strong, random passwords, using a variety of algorithms.

Comment: Browser integration does not only make life easier; it's also a great way to avoid phishing. A website can fool a user, but definitely not the browser and an extension. If you try to log into a site and password autocompletion doesn't kick in, it's a red flag!

Comment: It's probably worth saying that these are small incremental improvements rather than dramatic differences.  But switching to a password manager is both more usable and (slightly) more secure.

Comment: My worry with password managers is that they seem a very likely target for a hack. Whereas the secured file stored locally on my machine or usb-drive are not (assumptions on my part).

Comment: @CMB I use KeePass precisely because I run cross-platform: I sync my database over dropbox between Windows, Linux and Android systems.  The only problem is my Chromebook which has started refusing to install or run Android apps.

Comment: @dan you misunderstand a password manager slightly. If you get hacked it shouldn't matter because the idea is to have a very strong, unique  password encrypting the password manager - so even if  the cloud is hacked the passwords are safe.

Comment: Password manager can provide an automatic close and lock after a certain length of time, if you walk away and forget to close your encrypted text file it is unlikely to close itself.

Comment: @Deruijter, if you're too concerned with a cloud-based password manager, just get a local-only one, like KeePass or PasswordSafe or any number of other systems that store content only locally.

Comment: @user3067860 I can confirm that it doesn't close itself.  Something I have noticed that I didn't think of until I saw your comment is that when Veracrypt mounts a volume, it makes that volume available to all users on the system (total security flaw, even if it's just a setting I haven't tweaked).  If I switch to another user account, I can still access the mounted volume and the passwords inside.

Comment: @Dan Why would it matter if your passwords are saved to the cloud?  If someone managed to intercept them they shouldn't be able to open them anyway because of the encryption, right?

Comment: I think this answer should be more fine grained towards the downsides of using a password manager. While some encrypt their memory and keep the key inside a memory segment which will not be paged to disk (e. g. KeePass2 on Windows) others don't do so (e. g. KeePassXC on Debian). Also personally I think the crypto is a bit weaker depending on the tool used. The KeePass Database format does AES without Authentication and thus provides Confidentiality but no Integrity. `pass` on the other hand excellently uses raw gpg. VeraCrypt offers cryptography which I would consider stronger than KeePassDBs